# Problem with Vim omnicomplete and system Python

Tags: python, vim, omnicomplete

I have Vim set up, with `+python` (`:version` says it's ok). My `.vimrc` contains

```
filetype plugin on
set ofu=syntaxcomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType python setlocal omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
```

When some `.py` file is open, and I type i.e. `pri` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>, it says no pattern was found? Am I missing something? Can I somehow rebuild Vim's Python keyword database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than `syntaxcomplete#Complete`, use `pythoncomplete#Complete`:

```
# ~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim
setlocal omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete

# Or by autocmd
autocmd FileType python setlocal omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
```

[image: Python completion]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy all lines, I've got that, and the example you attached works. But it doesn't work for ie. "pri" (print"

Comment: @Marin mine doesn't complete `print` either, but completes all the harder to remember stuff. Not sure why it doesn't do basic language constructs, but it does function and module completion