# Can Omnicomplete in Vim for python/3 complete function names or just methods?

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, macvim, omnicomplete

To illustrate my question, here is a simple example of how Omnicomplete is acting on my machine:

```
name = "Bob"
na<C-x><C-o>      gives-----> name
name.<C-x><C-o>   gives-----> (correct dropdown menu of methods for string)
prin<C-x><C-o>    gives-----> (-- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found)
```

I was expecting the last line to expand to `print` or `print(` or something like that. Is this the correct behavior (Omnicomplete only does method completion for python/3)? If so, would function completion in the last case above be an example of what snippets are for?

I am using MacVim in the terminal with tmux. My `:version` says VIM 8.0. I have `+python/dyn` and `+python3/dyn` features. My `~/.vimrc` has this line (among others):

```
autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=python3complete#Complete
```

Right now, I'm only editing python3 files, so I *think* `omnifunc=python3...` is okay.

Semi-related SO post: [Problem with Vim omnicomplete and system Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271129/problem-with-vim-omnicomplete-and-system-python)

**EDIT:** I may have a workaround, though I don't know how to implement it.

Observe that:

```
 import builtins
 builtins.pr<C-x><C-o>   gives-----> (dropdown menu with print() and property()    )
 builtins.pri<C-x><C-o>  gives-----> (autocompletes to builtins.print(             )
```

Can this action with `<C-x><C-o>` be replicated without writing `import builtins` and using a `builtins` object? Perhaps a `<C-x><C-o>` search assumes `builtins.` if the string preceding `<C-x><C-o>` has no `.` in it?

I'm all ears for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Just set Omni Completion like it is recommended in the [Vim Wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Omni_completion) and it will work for all languages:

```
filetype plugin on
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use the following for the omnifunc:

```
autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
```